# Save variable in postbacks but clear/not preserve on leave page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make the value in a property persist after a postback in javascript. However, when I change pages I want this variable to be cleaned.

At this moment I have tried some ways:

- Hidden Field
- localStorage
- Global var
- document.cookie

My javascript file only contains one function, type the following:

```
function PropertiesSearchListingViewModelCreator(arg1, arg2, arg3)
{
      //Where do I want to preserve the variable
}
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood what you want to achieve but I guess you want to do something like this:

```
function myBeforePostBackFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('key');
});
```

Btw. using a `cookie` would also work as well as Hidden-Fields (at least with ASP.net (for more infos see [ModelState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx))).
Even `global variables` could work as long as you post the data by using ajax.